# Android sending push notification through .net webservices

Tags: java, web-services, google-cloud-messaging, android-ksoap2, android-webservice

I am using following webservice for sending Push notification from Android. When I call this webservice first time, it takes so much time and push notification is not delivered on Android Device. It happens only when called from Android. It works perfectly as webservice.

```
[WebMethod]

    public string SendGcm(String serviceKey,String registrationId ,string message) {
        WebClient wc=new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=" + serviceKey);
        NameValueCollection nameValues=new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"registration_id", registrationId},
                {"collapse_key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                {"data.payload", message}
            };

        var resp=wc.UploadValues("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
                    nameValues);

        var respMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
                return respMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Ideally it should not, but can u check if your code works with a test echo server instead of google server as well.

Comment: Probably due to Throttling http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling

Answer (score 0):

Use this - :

```
 public void MakeNotificationForAndroid(string DeviceToken, string Body, string Sound, string CustomFrom, string CustomeMsg)
        {
            String DeviceID = "";

            DeviceID = DeviceToken;
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AIzaSyBX1gD47uiVp0W_UjNxhwtVsQCNJYfg5vI"));

            String collaspeKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            //String postData=string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", DeviceID, "Pickup Message", collaspeKey);
            String postData = string.Format("registration_id={0}&data.message={1}&collapse_key={2}&data.sound={3}&data.type={4}", DeviceID, Body, collaspeKey, Sound, CustomeMsg);

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
        }
```